# Fail build if coverage lowers

Tags: python, unit-testing, continuous-integration, code-coverage, github-actions

I have GitHub Actions that build and test my Python application. I am also using `pytest-cov` to generate a code coverage report. This report is being uploaded to codecov.io.

I know that codecov.io can't fail your build if the coverage lowers, so how do I go about with GitHub Actions to fail the build if the coverage drops? Do I have to check the previous values and compare with the new "manually" (having to write a script)? Or is there an existing solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

One solution is that you can do a job with 2 steps which are :

1. Check if the coverage has dropped or not
2. Build in function of your result

If the step 1 fail, no build.
You can do a python script and return an error if the coverage drops.

Try something like that :

```
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-18.04

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v1
    - name: Set Up Python
      uses: actions/setup-python@v1
    - name: Test Coverage
      run: python check_coverage.py
    - name: Build
      if: success()
      run: python do_something.py # <= here you're doing your build
```

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing built-in, instead you should use one of the many integrations like sonarqube, if I don’t want to write a custom script.